# Add images to carousel within a listview xamarin forms

Tags: forms, listview, xamarin, carousel

Firts let me explain what I want to do. I have a listview which shows some products. When I click on a item, a window pops up with the details of that product. Now, in those details I want to show more pictures of that product with a carousel slide function and below those images I want to show the details and other stuff. This is what I made so far but the images won't show.

```
<ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout Padding="5,5,5,5">
            <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding productDetail}" HasUnevenRows="True"
                      x:Name="lstProductDetail">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <Grid x:Name="productDetailsGrid"
                          Padding="5, 5, 5, 5">
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Label Text="{Binding productHeader}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"
                                        TextColor="#FFFFFF"
                                        FontSize="25"
                                       BackgroundColor="Blue"
                                        FontAttributes="Bold"></Label>
                                <CarouselView Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1">
                                    <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="Center">
                                                <Image Source="{Binding productImage}"/>
                                            </StackLayout>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                                </CarouselView>
                                <Label Text="{Binding productPrice}" 
                                        FontSize="24"
                                        FontAttributes="Bold"
                                        TextColor="Red"
                                        Grid.Column="0"
                                        Grid.Row="2"/>
                                <Label Text="{Binding productDescription}" 
                                   FontSize="Medium" 
                                   TextColor="#000000"
                                   Grid.Column="0"
                                   Grid.Row="3"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
```

And in my .CSfile:

```
public IList<productDetails> productDetail { get; set; }
        private CultureInfo nfi = new CultureInfo("nl-NL", false);
        private int product_id;

        public Item Item { get; set; }
        public int productID {
            get { return product_id; }
            set { product_id = value; } 
        }
        public NewItemPage(int productId, string itemName)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            productDetail = new List<productDetails>();
            productDetail.Add(new productDetails { productHeader = "Test ding", productDescription = "Desc", productImage = "https://www.electronicabalie.nl/105297-large_default/philips-ce600n-2-din-autoradio-met.jpg", productManufacturer = "Manufacturer", productPrice = "129,95" });
            
            //loadProductDetail(productId);
            /*product_id = productId;
            Item = new Item
            {
                Text = itemName + " " + product_id.ToString(),
                Description = "This is description.",
                Id = product_id.ToString()
            };*/
            BindingContext = this;
        }
```

Public class part:

```
public class productDetails
        {
            public string productHeader { get; set; }
            public string productImage { get; set; }
            public string productManufacturer { get; set; }
            public string productPrice { get; set; }
            public string productDescription { get; set; }
        }
```

I think I need to add some extra array to add the images but somehow the carousel doesn't get the Binding for the images. Someone knows what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't set the **ItemsSource** of `CarouselView` .

#### in xaml

```
<CarouselView Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding ImageList}">
       <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                 <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="Center">
                      <Image Source="{Binding .}"/>
                 </StackLayout>
             </DataTemplate>
       </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
</CarouselView>
```

#### in model

```
public class productDetails
{
    public string productHeader { get; set; }
    public IList<string> ImageList { get; set; }
    public string productManufacturer { get; set; }
    public string productPrice { get; set; }
    public string productDescription { get; set; }
}
```

#### in ViewModel

```
 public ObservableCollection<productDetails> productDetail { get; set; }
```

```
public ViewModel()
        {

            productDetail = new ObservableCollection<productDetails>();

            for(int i = 0;i<5;i++)
            {
                var item = new productDetails()
                {
                    productHeader = "header",
                    productPrice = "$200.00",
                    productDescription = "Product Details",
                    productManufacturer = "xxx",
                    ImageList = new List<string>() {"test.png","test.png", "test.png" },

                };

                productDetail.Add(item);
            }          
        }
```

Comment: Aahh, I was almost there. Already tried with the ItemsSource within the carousel but didn't know how to add the data to it. Now it works just great! Thanks!